# which spring ws jaxb annotation to change xml element name

Tags: jaxb, spring-ws

I am using a sping ws endpoint with jaxb marshalling/unmarshalling to proudce a list of `Organisation` objects (our local type). The endpoint is SOAP 1.1, no parameters supplied on the request message.

I understand JAXB doesn't handle lists very well, so I use a wrapper class.

```
@XmlRootElement(name="orgResponse", namespace=....)
public class OrganisationListWrapper {

    private ArrayList<Organisation> organisationList;

    public getOrganisationList() {
        return organisationList;
    }

    public setOrganisationList(ArrayList<Organisation> organisationList) {
        this.organisationList = organisationList;
    }
}
```

The endpoint....

```
@PayloadRoot(localPart=.... namespace=....)
@ResponsePayload
public OrganisationListWrapper getOrganisations() {
    OrganisationListWrapper wrapper = new OrganisationListWrapper();
    wrapper.setOrganisationList(.... call service layer get list ....);
    return wrapper;
}
```

This works fine and I get a SOAP payload with

```
<orgResponse>
    <organisationList>
        ... contents of organisation 1
    </organisationList>
    <organisationList>
        ...  comtents of organisation 2
    </organisationList>
     .... etc ....
</orgResponse>
```

The Organisation class is not JAXB annotated. It is part of a large list of pre-existing classes that are being exposed through web services for the first time. Trying to get by without going in and annotating them all by hand.

I was able to override the name `OrganisationWrapper` with `orgResponse` in the `XmlRootElement` annotation. I would like to override the `organisationList` name in the child element with `organisation` but haven't been able to find an annotation that does this.

I can replace the array list name with `organisation` and it will work fine, but our coding standard here required us to put `List` on the end of our list names. I would like to try and stick to that. I have tried `XmlElement`, but that produced a jaxb exception.

Any suggestions would be appreciated.

Comment: Adding `@XmlElement` to the `organisationList` field is the way to go. What did you try, and what exception did you get?

Answer (score 1):

Because JAXB default the access type to PUBLIC_MEMBER, make sure you annotate the property (getter) and not the field:

```
@XmlElement(name="organisation")
public getOrganisationList() {
    return organisationList;
}
```

If you want to annotate the field then add the following annotation to your class:

```
@XmlAccessorType(XmlAccessType.FIELD)
```